# Reverse image search (Google's "Search by image") not producing useful results

Tags: image, image-processing

I would have thought Google Images' algorithms are by now sophisticated enough that their "Search by image" feature does a pretty good job idenityfing web pages where the same or a similar image can be found.

[image]

To my surprise, this seems to not be the case. I wanted for instance to identify where a certain location was (image below is from an unknown tourism website), and "Search by image" did a rubbish job at it (I know at least roughly where the pictured location should be).

[image]

Using the "visually similar" option in Google Images doesn't help, as images are suggested which are only roughly similar (mountains in this case), but clearly represent different locations.

To clarify, I am not expecting this kind of search to produce amazing results, such as invariance to lighting conditions, camera angle etc; but simply invariance to trivial image parameters such as cropping, global brightness adjustments etc

Since Google Images is clearly not (yet) the flagship reverse image search, can anyone recommend another search engine of this sort that can do the job?

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.” Also, the question has nothing at all to do with programming.

Comment: You are right. I thought people who are interested in things like APIs for Google Images/Maps, who are probably using this site, might have bumped into the same problem. Is there another SE site where it's better to ask, or should I just remove the question?

Comment: I think https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com might be suitable, but check their site policy, I haven’t been on there a lot.

Comment: will do - many thanks